# RFID does not respond after Ethernet.begin(mac, ip) initialization

Tags: arduino

Good day, I have this problem with my simple project. I have a database with all RFID number of employee. What I want to do is to use an rfID to check if it is registered in the database. If it is, it would return a value of 1 else would be a value of 0.

I tried with arduino HanRun Ethernet shield. I was able to get a response from the php web server to the serial monitor. Tried the seeedrfid it successfully get the rfcard number. However, when i tried to combine the two, it would hang on Ethernet.begin(mac, ip) initialization. My code is below.

```
    #include <Ethernet.h>
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #include <SeeedRFID.h>

    #define RFID_RX_PIN 10
    #define RFID_TX_PIN 11

    SeeedRFID RFID(RFID_RX_PIN, RFID_TX_PIN);

    char state = '0';
    char c;
    byte mac[] = {0x60, 0xF8, 0x1D, 0xBA, 0x1D, 0x52};
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 20, 228);

    EthernetClient client;

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Serial set up");

      Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
      Serial.print("My IP Address: ");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
    }

    void loop() {

      long rfID;
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

      if (RFID.isAvailable()) {
        rfID = RFID.cardNumber();
        Serial.println(rfID);
      }
}
```

Serial.println(rfID) is not executed unless I remove the Ethernet.begin(mac, ip). Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Thank you everyone for helping out. My supervisor who gave me the shield just remembered that there might be a pin changes(or anything you call it). That I might need to try other pin in order for the rf reader and ethernet shield to work together. now its working fine..

Comment: can you just give a timedelay just after Ethernet.begin(mac, ip); and try it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've tried it, unfortunately, its not working.

Comment: Can you tell me what you meant by not working. Can you update your question with your output.

Comment: i'd add some delay. However, nothing happen. I'd still need to comment out Ethernet.begin(mac, ip); in order for the rf card number to be printed in the serial.